# Getting "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER..." when trying to insert rows into SQLite via Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite

Anyone have any ideas? I get this error message in bash...

```
insert_code_sam.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
    "INSERT INTO index1 (name) VALUES ("test1");"
                                             ^
insert_code_sam.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
```

In a single file insert_code_sam.rb, I'm trying to create a new db, create two tables, and insert a test row. The SQlite table gets created without a problem, but I can't seem to insert rows.

```
require "sqlite3"

db = SQLite3::Database.new( "new_database.db" )

db.execute( 
  "CREATE TABLE index1 (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    name TEXT,
    tagline TEXT,
    blurb TEXT,
    photo_url TEXT);"
) 

db.execute( 
  "CREATE TABLE student_profile (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    name_id INTEGER,
    thumbnail_url TEXT,
    background_url TEXT,
    quote TEXT,
    bio TEXT,
    education TEXT,
    work TEXT,
    github TEXT,
    treehouse TEXT,
    codeschool TEXT,
    coderwall TEXT);"
) 

  db.execute(
    "INSERT INTO index1 (name) VALUES ("test1");"
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are prematurely ending the string – your code is not valid Ruby syntax. [SQLite expects single quoted strings, anyway](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html). The solution is to use single quotes for the `VALUES`:

```
db.execute(
  "INSERT INTO index1 (name) VALUES ('test1');"
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Same answer as Arup's but I'll accept yours since you've provided an explanation (for future users).

Answer (score 1):

```
db.execute(
    "INSERT INTO index1 (name) VALUES ('test1');"
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way if you wanted to use `""` delimiter:

```
db.execute(
    "INSERT INTO index1 (name) VALUES (\"test1\");"
  )
```

Comment: Are you saying this is better format in general than simply changing double quotes to single quotes?

Comment: In Ruby a big difference present in strings which are delimited with `'` and `''`. So If you are using `"`,then you need to escape it using `\\`.